# Clicking on link on JEditorPane throws IOException

Tags: java, swing

I have written this code to JEditorPane's Hyperlink update event

```
private void outHyperlinkUpdate(javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent evt) {   

    if (evt.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(evt.getURL().toURI());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                trayIcon.showMessage(null, ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code throws an IOException:
"java.io.IOException: Failed to open https://www.google.com. Error message: A device attached to the system is not functioning."

Please bring me out from this error and also help me to understand this error.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for Desktop.browse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) answers this question:

> Throws: **IOException** - if the user default browser is not found, or it fails to be launched, or the default handler application failed to be launched.

This can e.g. happen if you have not set a default browser

Comment: Default browser is Google Chrome

Comment: what happens if you paste the url into the windows search bar?